# How to create a drilldown in a DevExpress ASPxGridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, devexpress, drilldown

In the DevExpress GridView component, how do you create a drilldown to a detail page? The app is in MVC 2.

eg One column of the grid has a hyperlink, and clicking that link takes you to the detail edit page (not an inline editor) for that row's data record:

```
+------------+---+
|Red widget  | 5 |
|Blue widget | 3 |
+------------+---+
```

Where clicking on "red widget" will take you to the "/Product/Edit/1" page, and clicking on "blue widget" will take you to the "/Product/Edit/2" page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Grid View - Editing](http://mvc.devexpress.com/GridView/Editing) demo module.